# Pass variables from javascript to yii via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii

I am writing a Yii application (or I should say building on top of someone else's Yii application!). I need to use quite a lot of javascript, because I'm using the Leaflet map library. So a lot of this is external to the PHP code and called with `registerScriptFile`, `registerScript` etc.

To get data from the javascript into the main Yii application, I have been using AJAX calls.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "xxx/index.php/site/updateajax",
    data: {recordID: feature.properties.id}
}).success(function(result){
    $("#recordTable").replaceWith(result);
});
```

and

```
public function actionUpdateAjax()
{
    $data = $_POST['recordID'];
    $this->renderPartial('/map/_legend_layers', array('data' => $data),false,false);
}
```

in the php. I discovered I needed to call `$("#element").replaceWith(result);` because otherwise the rendering was being returned but not being rendered.

In this case this works OK because I can call replaceWith, but I have a nagging feeling this isn't the right way to do it, and also I have another AJAX call that renders a whole page so I can't really replace that.

My question is how can I either force the html returned by these AJAX  calls to render the page, or more likely I suppose, how can I just use AJAX to update a variable, return back a success code or something, then let the yii code carry on and do it's thing - I'm only using AJAX as a variable passing mechanism.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks normal to me . . . you're using renderPartial to generate HTML, and then you're using the callback in your AJAX to put that HTML where you want it via replaceWith.  For the second use case where you mention you want a whole page, it sounds like you'll want to render the page, rather that do a renderPartial . . .

The one change I'd make is to use a success callback in the actual [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call, rather than the jqXHR.success() method that's going to be deprectated in 1.8, i.e.:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "xxx/index.php/site/updateajax",
    data: {recordID: feature.properties.id},
    success: function(result){ $("#recordTable").replaceWith(result); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, have added what worked for me as an answer based on your answer

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I needed to replace the whole page with the html from an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "xxx",
success: function(result){
document.open();
document.write(result);
document.close();
});
```

The only issue I've found so far is that it doesn't update the url...

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, if you want to redirect to a completely new page instead of updating a page dynamically, you'll likely want to change the call in the PHP from `renderPartial()` to [render()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#render-detail).  You'll be able to skip the javascript success function then, as Yii will redirect to the new page.  You'll want the `$return` parameter to be the default false . . .

Comment: I might be missing something here, but that's what I was doing, and I can see the response rendered in the "Network" tab of my Debugging console, but not in the page itself. I don't seem to be able to fire a request off to Yii and Yii takes back control. The exact command is   $this->render('create',array(
   'model'=>$project,false
  ));

Comment: Oh, I should have mentioned that in this second case, you'll want to just call the action directly (likely in the form itself), instead of using an ajax call as you're not looking to do anything async

Comment: And if I need to pass a variable .... such as data: {recordID: feature.properties.id} in my example? Apologies for all the questions btw, just trying to understand what is going on.